# Hyperlink to bibliography reference

Tags: reference-managers, cross-referencing

In Microsoft Word and Mendeley, is it possible to jump to the complete reference in the bibliography section of a document using a hyperlink?

For example, using "Ctrl+Left Click" on figures or table cross-references will take to the corresponding table.

Answer (score 2):

### The Manual Way

Microsoft Word supports hyperlinks within documents. For instance, in the version of Word I have (Office Professional 2016), when I attempt to add a hyperlink ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVbTt.png)), the menu gives me the option of hyperlinking a "Place in This Document."

[image]

If you use [styles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109) to designate text Headers in Word, you will see those listed under "Headings" and can use those as links. Alternatively, you can set Bookmarks in Word ([2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109)), and then use hyperlinks to point to those bookmarks.

So you would need to set bookmarks for each reference and then put hyperlinks at each in-text mention. It's time consuming, but it works, and these links are even preserved if you're eventually saving to PDF.

([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVbTt.png)) You can add a hyperlink by selecting text or a point in the document and (a) right-clicking and selecting Hyperlink; (b) navigating from the top menu - Insert -> Hyperlink; (c) using "Add a Hyperlink" from the search function; (d) pressing Ctrl + K.

([2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109)) You can add a bookmark by selecting text or a point in the document and (a) navigating from the top menu - Insert -> Bookmark, (b) searching for "Insert a Bookmark" from the search function, (c) pressing Ctrl + Shift + F5.

### The Macros Way

If you want the functionality to be friendly with Mendeley, you may need a third-party solution like mabentwickeltsich's [Mendeley Macros](https://github.com/mabentwickeltsich/MendeleyMacros) on GitHub, which works for APA and IEEE. For this and other third-party tools, you would want to read the user documentation and make sure you understand what it's doing. That said, they do automate the process.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Word supports linking within documents: Such functionality can be embedded. However, Word can be used in terrible ways, such functionality might not be embedded.